# how to use 128-bit register in rk3399 by neon?

Tags: c++, neon

I want to use neon to optimize my cpp code.
And what I use is rk3399 (http://wiki.t-firefly.com/index.php/Firefly-RK3399/en ),it should have 32 128_bit registers.
And I write single codes to compare the cost of time of whether I use neon

```
//sample code A
for (int i = 0; i < vLen; i++)
{   
    ans[i] = f[i] + q[i];
}   

//sample code B    
for (int i = 0; i < vLen; i += 4)
{
    int32x4_t p = vld1q_s32(f + i);
    int32x4_t o = vld1q_s32(q + i);
    int32x4_t tmp = vaddq_s32 (p, o);
    vst1q_s32 ((int32_t*)&ans[i], tmp);
}
```

I thought the code B should cost 1/4 of code A.But actually, the cost of code A and B are almost same.
I want to know why and how to use 128-bit register to optimize my code.

By the way, when the data type is not int32_t but int8_t, the code B will cost only 1/4 time of code A. It seems that only 32-bit register have been used.

Comment: did you check the assembly output of the compiler? The compiler might have optimized "Code A" with neon instruction by itself.

Comment: Look at [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/xQ9gxa) both versions use NEON instructions. In addition the bottleneck in your software might also be other things than just the ALU, it could also be memory fetches or other factors.